# Was the stutter intentional?

Tags: gamers-dorkness-rising

In the movie [The Gamers: Dorkness Rising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gamers%3a_Dorkness_Rising), the character Lodge says "no, you don't" at one point, but he kind of stutters it.  This is the only time this character stutters in this movie.  Was this an editing issue?  Was this intentional?

Comment: Can you provide a guide as to *when* this happened in the film? I looked through the script and searched the movie on YouTube, but the two instances when Lodge says "no, you don't" sound totally normal...

Comment: @AndrewMartin sorry for the super late response.  The scene is when they are restarting the campaign and bickering about monks and elves.

Comment: I've watched [the scene you're referring to](https://youtu.be/tOUksDJCijw?t=15m56s) a couple of times and I'm struggling to identify where any of the characters stutter.

Answer (score 1):

The only instance I can find where the character Lodge says "no, you don't" seems to be here;

I can't hear any evidence of a stutter, nor any good reason why his character would have stumbled over his words.